# CSS Stretch to Available Width

Tags: css, html, width

How do I make a block-level element, such as a `div` stretch to the available width?

I know that this may seem like a question with an obvious answer, but it is a tad bit more complicated that it seems, have a look at this Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/spryno724/pZKgv/

The CSS sets a left and right margin for the containing `div` to 20% on each side. Setting the `width` property causes it to stretch 100% of the *original* available space, causing it to spill off the side of the screen when the 20% margins are added to each side.

How can this be fixed, such that 20% margins still exist, but the `div` stretches to fill the remaining space in between?

Comment: Dave, that should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Uhmmmm..... *light-headed feeling* Yes. I don't know why I didn't think of that??? Thank you Dave.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what you had:

```
.error {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}​
```

Try this one:

```
.error {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  top: 0;
}​
```

Comment: It depends on what you want to do... you need fixed if you want to position your div relative to the browser window... (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)

Comment: Yes, I do want it fixed relative to the browser window

Comment: Then set the width to 60% like others suggested.

Answer (score 2):

the cleanest way i see you going about this aside from the mentioned fix (setting the width to 60%) is to enclose that error div inside a container and add the `position:fixed` property to that. That way you can style your error message and not have to worry about style issues that might arise from positioning the element itself (like a bleeding background color, padding, or overflow issues).

**HTML**

```
<div class="fixed">
    <div class="error">Error!!!</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.error {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 20%;
}


.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pZKgv/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure body has `0` padding and margin.

Any `div` inside should take every bit of space available.